# General inverse of constant correlation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an $n\times n$ matrix whose i, j element is defined by:
$$
a_{ij} = (1 - \rho) \delta_{ij} + \rho
$$

Is there a general expression for the inverse of that matrix?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes: symmetry suggests the inverse matrix should look similar in form (a constant on the diagonal and a different constant everywhere else).  You can easily find these two constants (based on $\rho$ and $n$) via two linear simultaneous equations if you try to multiply the two matrices.  What have you tried?

Comment: You may have problems if $\rho =1$ or $\rho=-\frac1{n-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix clearly has no inverse for $\rho=1$ unless $n=1$, the case $\rho = 0$ is trivial.
For $\rho \neq 0$ the expression for the matrix can be written as
\begin{align}
A = (1-\rho)I + \rho e e^T = \rho \left( \frac{1-\rho}{\rho} I + e e^T\right)
\end{align}
where I is the $n\times n$ identity matrix and $e$ is a vector full of ones, $e^T = (1,\dots, 1)$.
This fits the structure for [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) since it is a sum of an invertible matrix and rank one correction. This formula gives an expression for the inverse as well as the condition that the inverse does exist if and only if $\rho \neq -\frac{1}{n-1}$.

Application of the formula gives
\begin{align}
\left( \frac{1-\rho}{\rho} I + e e^T\right)^{-1} &= \frac{\rho}{1-\rho}I - \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\rho}{1-\rho} e^T e } \left(\left(\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right)^2 I e e^T I \right), \\
&= \frac{\rho}{1-\rho}I - \frac{\rho^2}{(1-\rho)^2 + \rho(1-\rho)n}ee^T.
\end{align}
Consequently
\begin{align}
A^{-1} = \frac{1}{1-\rho}I - \frac{\rho}{(1-\rho)^2 + \rho(1-\rho)n}ee^T.
\end{align}

Comment: Alternative answer is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516437/inverting-the-matrix-i-v-vt?rq=1). I have written out this one since this is one of the few cases where the Sherman Morrison formula is actually useful.